# display:inline-block not displaying correctly

Tags: css, html

I have a couple of divs that use this CSS:

```
           .CellDiv 
           {
               display:inline-block;
               width: 130px;
               height: 90px;
           }
```

When I run this in my dev environment it displays correctly, aligns the divs horizontally.
When I put it on the web server they start displaying vertically.

How to fix that behaviour?

The browser is IE10

CSS file:

```
/* DEFAULTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

body  
{
    background: Black;
    font-size: .80em;
    font-family:'Segoe WP';
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: black;
}

a:link, a:visited
{
    color: #034af3;
}

/*a:hover
{
    color: #1d60ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
    color: #034af3;
}*/

p
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}


/* HEADINGS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #666666;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 2.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6
{
    font-size: 1em;
}

/* this rule styles <h1> and <h2> tags that are the 
first child of the left and right table columns */
.rightColumn > h1, .rightColumn > h2, .leftColumn > h1, .leftColumn > h2
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.page
{
    /*width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;*/
}

.header
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1
{
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.leftCol
{
    padding: 6px 0px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.footer
{
    color: #4e5766;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
}


/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* FORM ELEMENTS   
----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset
{
    margin: 1em 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset p 
{
    margin: 2px 12px 10px 10px;
}

fieldset.login label, fieldset.register label, fieldset.changePassword label
{
    display: block;
}

fieldset label.inline 
{
    display: inline;
}

legend 
{
    color:White;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 2px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input.textEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.passwordEntry 
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.accountInfo
{
    width: 42%;
}

/* MISC  
----------------------------------------------------------*/

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}

.title
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.loginDisplay
{
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    color: White;
}

.loginDisplay a:link
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:visited
{
    color: white;
}

.loginDisplay a:hover
{
    color: white;
}

.failureNotification
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: Red;
}

.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.submitButton
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.highlightRow tr:hover 
{
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.grayRow
{
    background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: Are there any other CSS sheets or JavaScript involved that could be overriding it, that wasn't updated on the server?  Did you try using the dev console (F12) to inspect/trace the CSS? Is this happening in other browsers (Chrome, FF, etc)?  Sorry, there's not much to go off of here to help.

Comment: Can you include your HTML, jsfiddle, screenshots? any or all will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#Monkviper {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: The OP specifies the problem persists in IE10.  The code you've provided is for getting inline-block to work properly in IE<8.